# Trying to fade out CCLabelTTF, change text, and then fade back in

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, opacity, unrecognized-selector, fadeto, cclabelttf

I am trying to make CCLabelTTF change its text every 10 seconds using an array of strings.
This is the code I have so far, but it is giving me this error!

```
2013-09-07 15:47:34.618 MazeIt[6271:1b503] -[TitleLayer opacity]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa553bb0
```

If anyone who is more experienced with runAction and CCLabel could help me out, it would be extremely helpful!

This is the code I have:
I have _list which is the array of strings, _text which is CCLabelTTF which I want to manipulate

```
In init _text and _list is created:
[self schedule:@selector(callback) interval:10.0f];

-(void) callback
{
    id fadeIn = [_text runAction:[CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:0.5 opacity:127]];
    id fadeOut = [_text runAction:[CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:0.5 opacity:255]];
    id change = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:_text selector: @selector(changeText:)];
    id sequence = [CCSequence actions: fadeIn, change, fadeOut, nil];
    [self runAction: sequence];
}
- (void)changeText:(id)sender{
    [_text setString:@"You completed no levels!"];
//    [_text setString:_list[0]];
//    [_text setString:_list[_next%[_list count]]];
    _next++;
}
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOL my bad it was a really simple error, and some tweaking fixed it!
I am just going to leave this up here in case someone else is trying to do the same thing!
The correct code is:

```
-(void) callback
{
    id fadeIn = [CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:0.5 opacity:0];
    id fadeOut = [CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:0.5 opacity:255];
    id change = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector: @selector(changeText:)];
    id sequence = [CCSequence actions: fadeIn, change, fadeOut, nil];
    [_text runAction: sequence];
}
```